# Angular with MVC tells me error Not found 404

Tags: angularjs, asp.net-mvc

I am using AngularJs with Microsoft ASP.NET MVC when i can get records from Database and Insert new item to Database but when i update item i get Error Not found 404

Here is my code

C# code:

```
    [HttpPut]
public void UpdateContinent(Continent Con)
{

    MyDatabaseEntities db = new MyDatabaseEntities();
    Continent conti = db.Continents.Find(Con.ContinentId);
    conti.ContinentName = conti.ContinentName;
    db.SaveChanges();

}
```

Angular:

```
app.controller("myCntrl", function ($scope, $http) {


    $scope.Continent = {
        ContinentId: '',
        ContinentName: ''
    };


    $scope.Update = function (con) {
        $scope.Continent = con;
        $http.post('/Home/UpdateContinent', { Con: $scope.Continent })
        .success(function (data) {
            $('#DivForEdit').modal('hide');
            $scope.clear();
            $scope.GetAll();
        })
        .error(function (msg) {
            alert(msg)
        })
    }
```

I have tried  this code inside web.config file:

```
<system.webServer>
    <handlers>
      <remove name="ExtensionlessUrlHandler-Integrated-4.0" />
      <add name="ExtensionlessUrlHandler-Integrated-4.0"
           path="*." verb="GET,HEAD,POST,DEBUG,PUT,DELETE"
           type="System.Web.Handlers.TransferRequestHandler"
           resourceType="Unspecified" requireAccess="Script"
           preCondition="integratedMode,runtimeVersionv4.0" />
    </handlers>
  </system.webServer>
```

It didn't work, then i replaced with this code and didn't work too:

```
  <system.webServer>
    <validation validateIntegratedModeConfiguration="false" />
    <handlers>
      <remove name="ExtensionlessUrlHandler-ISAPI-4.0_32bit" />
      <remove name="ExtensionlessUrlHandler-ISAPI-4.0_64bit" />
      <remove name="ExtensionlessUrlHandler-Integrated-4.0" />
      <add name="ExtensionlessUrlHandler-ISAPI-4.0_32bit" path="*." verb="GET,HEAD,POST,DEBUG,PUT,DELETE,PATCH,OPTIONS" modules="IsapiModule" scriptProcessor="%windir%\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\aspnet_isapi.dll" preCondition="classicMode,runtimeVersionv4.0,bitness32" responseBufferLimit="0" />
      <add name="ExtensionlessUrlHandler-ISAPI-4.0_64bit" path="*." verb="GET,HEAD,POST,DEBUG,PUT,DELETE,PATCH,OPTIONS" modules="IsapiModule" scriptProcessor="%windir%\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0.30319\aspnet_isapi.dll" preCondition="classicMode,runtimeVersionv4.0,bitness64" responseBufferLimit="0" />
      <add name="ExtensionlessUrlHandler-Integrated-4.0" path="*." verb="GET,HEAD,POST,DEBUG,PUT,DELETE,PATCH,OPTIONS" type="System.Web.Handlers.TransferRequestHandler" preCondition="integratedMode,runtimeVersionv4.0" />
    </handlers>
  </system.webServer>
```

Please help me. i am new in Angular.....

Thanks in Advance

Comment: Where is `$scope.GetAll()` implemented?

Comment: Is `/Home/UpdateContinent` route handler implemented?

Comment: You are using  [HttpPut] in service and post in angular, change both to post or put

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `UpdateContinent` method is set as `[HttpPut]` but you are sending the request with `$http.post`, you should use `$http.put` instead:

```
$scope.Update = function (con) {
    $scope.Continent = con;
    $http.put('/Home/UpdateContinent', { Con: $scope.Continent })
    .success(function (data) {
        $('#DivForEdit').modal('hide');
        $scope.clear();
        $scope.GetAll();
    })
    .error(function (msg) {
        alert(msg)
    })
}
```